# Correct parsing of JSON

Tags: javascript, html, jsonp

First of all, forgive me if any of this code is bad, inefficient, or completely wrong, I haven't worked with JSON at all before, or any sort of API work.

So, I'm just trying to create a basic webpage which will display some information from the JSON obtained through JSONP (did I implement it correctly...?). I thought that I was accessing the id element correctly but it seems not as I've tried getting it to show up with alert, console.log, and setting the inner html of the paragraph. Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id="main">
            test
        </p>                                                                                                                                                          
    </body>
    <script src="js/parseJSON.js"></script>
    <script type="application/json" src="https://www.aviationweather.gov/gis/scripts/MetarJSON.php?taf=true&bbox=-86,41,-82,45&callback=parseJSON"></script>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
var parseJSON =  function(json) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(json);

    console.log(obj.features[0].properties.id); 
}
```

This seems like something simple I'm just screwing up. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm just trying to create a basic webpage which will display some information from the JSON obtained through JSONP (did I implement it correctly...?).

You said `type="application/json"` so the browser ignored it because it doesn't know how to execute scripts written in JSON.

JSONP is not JSON, it is JavaScript, so the correct Content Type is `application/javascript`.

Further `https://www.aviationweather.gov/gis/scripts/MetarJSON.php?taf=true&bbox=-86,41,-82,45&callback=parseJSON` returns JSON not JSONP.

> ```
> var parseJSON =  function(json) {
>     var obj = JSON.parse(json);
> ```

While it is possible for a JSONP service to provide data in the form of a JavaScript string containing JSON, that is never something I've seen. The argument should not be parsed as JSON. It should be a regular JavaScript data structure.

… but first you need the service to return JSONP.

Comment: Thank you! I think I know what the problem is now. Looking back at the documentation page I made a mistake, the "callback" should instead be "jsonp" in the url. Will give it a try! EDIT: Yep, got it working. thanks!